# how can we use variable in file as input to another variable in ansible

Tags: file, variables, ansible

I need to use one variable defined in file in various subsequent variables inside files.

```
URL_host: XXX.XX.XX.XX
```

is my variable

I need to use it like

```
JDBCURL: {{ URL_host }}/jdbc
mysqlrpm: {{ URL_host }}/mysql.rpm
```

Is it feasible in ansible

Comment: [include_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html)?

Comment: please be more elaborate about your question, and where are these variables present, as Ansible has an order of precedence for variables, present in different scopes

Comment: Hi ,I have placed this variables in groups_vars/variables.yml .I am using currently single variable file in system and want user should edit this single file only ,thats why i need to use one variable defined above to be used as subsequent input to another variable as explained in my example

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have included the `URL_HOST` var in a file you can include that file using [vars_files](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-file-separation) or `include_vars` providing the file path.

Then you should be able to do something like "{{ URL_host }}"/jdbc